# Line throwing syntax error from sh file but not command line

Tags: linux, bash

This line which moves unopened files from a directory to a sub directory is causing a `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error. It runs without any syntax errors from the command line but if I run it within a bash file, oddly it throws this syntax error.

```
comm -2 -3 <(find $DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f|sort) <(sudo lsof $DIR/* | awk '(NR>1) {print $9}'|sort) | xargs -I {} mv {} $DIR/tmp
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your `/bin/sh` is probably not bash. If you're going to use bashisms, use `/bin/bash` as the shebang line.

Comment: use `set -x` in the bash to show the debugging. Also, break up the commands into shell variables and use them instead. All on one line at first looks cramped and difficult to spot.

Comment: Try a simple example. I have the same with `cat <(echo file)`.

Comment: @ninjalj, I do have this set as `#!/bin/bash`. For some reason if I use "bash" to open the file, it works but not "sh".

Comment: @user2980769: If you invoke `sh`, the script is interpreted by `sh`, which in your case is `dash`, not by the shell specified in the shebang line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your commands are interpreted by bash.

I had the same problem with the (simplified) script `cat <(echo file)`. 
If the shebang line is missing or not recognized, /bin/sh is used.
On my system the `/bin/sh` is not a link to bash, and the command will fail.
Adding the shebang makes my script working:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <(echo file)
```